# Update newly created record's lookup field, using Id from just created lookup relationship

Tags: javascript, lookup

I need to create a new **Case**, populate the **Case's** lookup Project__c field with the Id of the **Project** which the **Case** has been created from, then populate the Program__c lookup field with the Id of the **Program** which the **Project** is related to.

Here's what I have so far:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 

try{ 
    var recToCreate = new sforce.SObject("Case");
    recToCreate.Project__c = '{!MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c.Id}';
    var result = sforce.connection.create([recToCreate]); 
    if(result[0].success == "true"){

// add Project's related Program - should this be a separate loop?
// how can I reference the newly created Case in the SOQL query?
var myquery = "SELECT Id, FROM Case WHERE Project__c = {result[0].ProjectId__c} limit 1";
result = sforce.connection.query(myquery); 

// update Program__c lookup field with Program Id - how?
result = sforce.connection.update([recToCreate]);
    }
    else{
        alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + result[0].errors.message);
    }
}
catch(e){
    alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + e);
}
```

The API name of the Project field's lookup to the Program is MPM4_BASE__Program__c.

I'm new to JavaScript and can't work out how to reference the new **Case's** Project Id in the SOQL query, in order to find it's related **Program**. I'm also not sure how to then update the new **Case** once the **Program** lookup field has been populated or whether the first loop should be closed before an update 'try' is started?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive. Please make sure that you are using correct case for object names,fields etc. Also you should set authentication token. You can try something like below code,

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
    sforce.connection.sessionId = ‘ {!$Api.Session_ID}’;

    try {
        var recToCreate = new sforce.SObject("Case");
        recToCreate.Project__c = '{!MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c.Id}';
        var result = sforce.connection.create([recToCreate]);
        if (result[0].success == "true") {

            // add Project's related Program. Query project object with project Id
            var myquery = "SELECT Id,Program__c FROM Case WHERE Project__c = \'{result[0].ProjectId__c}\' limit 1";
            result = sforce.connection.query(myquery);
            var records = result.getArray("records");
            if (records.length != 0) {
                recToCreate.Program__c = records[0].Program__c;
                result = sforce.connection.update([recToCreate]);
            }
        } else {
            alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + result[0].errors.message);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + e);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an error 'unexpected token ILLEGAL'?

Comment: Try putting console.log() or alert() statements to find till what line it is executing. Then based on that that you can find line of error and fix it. Please keep in min that it is case sensitive.

Comment: So should I add a try & catch with alert() for each line? (sorry, again I'm new to this).

Comment: simple alert also will do. It will help you to find line with bug.

Comment: I've added console.log('#1'); etc. after each line in the code, for example         var result = sforce.connection.create([recToCreate]); console.log('#3'); but nothing's showing up in the developer console in Chrome when I click the button?

Comment: you are checking in browser console right?. It will not come in salesforce developer console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23473/discussion-between-alex-s-and-victor).